# Сортировка массива

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Доброго времени суток, не могли бы вы подсказать какой сортировкой массива и как в данном случае лучше воспользоваться?

```
package com.example.proverka;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class proverka {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Сгенерировать массив целых чисел случайным образом ,вывести его на экран,отсортировать его,и снова вывести на экран.");
        System.out.println("Введите количество элементов массива");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        Random m = new Random();
        int mas[]= new int[n];
        System.out.println("Случайный массив=");
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            mas[i]=m.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println( mas[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как насчет Arrays.sort(mas) ?

Comment: А каким образом правильно реализовать Arrays.sort(mas)?
Я пробовал, но у меня ,к сожалению не вышло

Comment: Почему не вышло? В вашем случае этот метод отсортирует ваш массив по возрастанию

Comment: Вот, написал после цикла, но ничего не произошло

for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            mas[i]=m.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println( mas[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(mas);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mas));

Comment: А вы сколько элементов массива вводите с клавиатуры?

Comment: Пробовал меньше 10, при большем все работает,только что проверил

Comment: Понял свою ошибку)
Благодарю за помощь)

Comment: Просто вы просите пользователя указать количество элементов, сохраняете в переменной, но выводите все равно только 10 элементов